fastAPI OAuth2 redirect failing with error "Auth ErrorTypeError: Failed to fetch"
I'm trying to implement a simple fastAPI system which requires OAuth2 with authorization-code flow. In a router, I've configured OAuth2 scheme in route.py like,
# OAuth2 configuration
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer(
    authorizationUrl=<auth_url>,
    tokenUrl=<token_url>,
    scopes={scope:scope},
)

and with a custom redirect uri, which is configured in main.py like
app = FastAPI(swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url="/route/oauth2-redirect").
When trying to test using /docs swagger UI -> Authorize button, its going for the provider site & authorizing, as the terminal shows the successful redirected url with code like this,

"GET /route/oauth2-redirect?code=7yFB%21IAAAAL3crO9Rl-Z8tH814uZJx3dOE4JWn2j7KCunPBdfJj1cAQEAAAGvKH7b3aEL1GanDXYUYt9xm4Z4bPGBTjhZZUg0MVlUP9zF6zxmj336AemvbFc_Hk0rdJfDqZTN5m7Lb0uI95edFjgezbDhvYG_wi8l2j0zx6IkgzwMD-2_VtRP8S25KD7j2622kRijZOkfhPAI6q0v5mdn0LeC3MQvnOYzN7El4YCxQ6CuaFaKEu08xYYPyTGlCxoIp4eApXbwbRrM0zBlSVXQoJNQnxSnogK9UjdigDYyrQYQBlYvYpNIhFVDqWr0UxT6kmv18USIBRwjWaP-8oqAopkxHs6EuxPtYHy9SPHHxrWDeiLL6IXD7CW-W736c2LbMNi2jGlOQmM2J4uU&state=RnJpIEp1biAyMSAyMDI0IDIwOjUzOjE1IEdNVCswNTMwIChJbmRpYSBTdGFuZGFyZCBUaW1lKQ%3D%3D HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

But, on returning to the /docs UI it gives error "Auth Error  TypeError: Failed to fetch", due to which the Authorization is failing. There's no other error in terminal. Not sure if I'm missing anything.
My requirement is, on receiving the Auth_Code, need to post it to token url along with other details like client_id, client_secret, scopes in the request body instead of request header
Once authorized, I have to test if token is working for protected endpoints,
@router.get("/protected-endpoint", dependencies=[Depends(oauth2_scheme)]) async def protected(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
I tried adding CORS to the app in main.py but no change in the observations,
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)

Any reference to working examples OR existing question leading to the required solution (which I tried but failed finding) is appreciated.   Thanks in advance!

Did you solve your issue, i have the same.
